# Kinda complex inner join and sum query

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, inner-join

I am stuck with a query and would appreciate if you guys could help me.

We are using a table (MS Access) to store project plans for multiple companies as follows:

```
ID    PROJECT_NAME   COMPANY_NAME   MILESTONE_NAME   MILESTONE_TYPE
```

The objective of my query is to return the count of "applicable" rollouts.

A rollout is the unique combination of project and company. Example:

```
Project 1 being executed in the Company A
Project 2 being executed in the Company A
Project 1 being executed in the Company B
```

An applicable project is whatever project which it last milestone has a MILESTONE_TYPE different than "DUMMY".

An applicable rollout should look like this:

```
ID    PROJECT_NAME   COMPANY_NAME   MILESTONE_NAME           MILESTONE_TYPE
1     Project 3      Company D      6.2 Rollout Completed    Applicable
```

In order to retrieve the last milestone of the project I am using the following SQL:

```
SELECT Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME], MAX(Sheet1.[MILESTONE_NAME])
FROM Sheet1
    INNER JOIN Sheet1 AS Sheet1_1 ON (Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME] = Sheet1_1.[PROJECT_NAME])
        AND (Sheet1.[MILESTONE_NAME] = Sheet1_1.[MILESTONE_NAME])
GROUP BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME]
ORDER BY Sheet1.[PROJECT_NAME]
```

The expected result of the query I need your support would be:

```
PROJECT_NAME  COUNT_OF_APPLICABLE_ROLLOUTS
Project A     5
Project B     6
```

However I have absolutely no idea how to even get started...
Does anyone know how to put in all in a SQL query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: given the example, what would be your desired result?

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that bigger "id" means later, the following query returns information about the latest non-dummy row:

```
select p.*
from Sheet1.p join
     (select project_name, company_name, max(id) as maxid
      from Sheet1
      where Milestone_Name <> 'Dummy'
      group by project_name, company_name
     ) pc
     on p.project_name, pc.company_name
```

(Note:  I haven't tested this so it might have syntax errors.)

Comment: Thx gordon however it is not working. The ID is not the field which determines what the latest milestones within a rollout is. Therefore I had to write the SQL query to retrieve them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    SELECT  myTable.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT COMPANY_NAME
        FROM    Sheet1
        ) CN
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 *
        FROM    Sheet1 myTable2
        WHERE   myTable2.COMPANY_NAME = CN.COMPANY_NAME
        ORDER BY
                MILESTONE_NAME DESC
        ) myTable
```

Comment: Thx but it is not working though! It seems the cross apply generates an error when using with MS Access